# jQuery matching Href to div ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to match the HREF of the li elements with an ID of a DIV inside a gallery DIV with `ID="gallery"`.

`alert()` seems to return the correct href attributes but I can't manage to find the ID of the matching element and change it's css display property to visible;

```
<ul>

   <li><a class="contentUpdate" href="#logo_branding">Logo Design & Branding</a></li>


   <li><a class="contentUpdate" href="#webdesign">Web Design</a></li>


   <li><a class="contentUpdate" href="#mobileuidesign">Mobile UI Design</a></li>


</ul>


$(".contentUpdate").click(function() {
   var href = $(this).attr("href");
   alert(href);
});
```

Comment: Where is div gallery

Comment: Where you are using ID?

Comment: It is the next DIV right after the UL

Comment: I don't see any `DIV` in the code that you have posted.

Comment: $(href).show().siblings().hide();  did exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `mobileuidesign` is the id of div when `href` is `#mobileuidesign`, then href can be used for creating object of element with id `mobileuidesign`:

```
$(".contentUpdate").click(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  $(href).show();
});
```

Comment: Hi is it possible to disable href and only class click works and still get the div from the href?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee: Do you want to prevent redirect on href?

Comment: Correct but with validation on click

Answer (score 0):

You must be first enter id in href
$(".contentUpdate").click(function() {var href = $(this).attr("href");$(href).attr('id');});

Answer (score 0):

`href has # too`. where div id dost. you `replace` to replace `# to nothing`

```
$(".contentUpdate").click(function() {
   var href = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
   alert(href);
});
```